Can find_if be used to find a key in std::map/std::unordered_map?
This is a simple program consisting of adding an element into the std::unordered_map. But before it's added, first check if the key already exists, if it does then don't add it.
My problem is that since find_if requires only one parameter to be passed in the lambda function, I'm having trouble implementing this since an element on the std::unordered_map is a pair of two types. I wonder if it's even possible to use find_if and if not what's the best way to accomplish this?
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map <std::string_view, int> myDictionary{};

void addEmployee(std::string_view newName, int newTime)
{
    // first check if they name already exists, if it does then do nothing and return
    auto it{std::find_if(myDictionary.begin(), myDictionary.end(),
                         [&newName]( ??? )
    {
        return newName == myDictionary.first;
    })};

    if (it != myDictionary.end() )
    {
        std::cout << "Name already exists! Wasn't added.\n";
        return;
    }

    // add employee into the map
    myDictionary.insert(std::pair<std::string_view,int> (newName, newTime) );

}

void printDict( std::unordered_map<std::string_view, int>& myDict)
{
    for (auto const& a: myDict)
        std::cout << a.first << " " << a.second << "\n";
}
int main()
{

    addEmployee("Daniel", 14);
    addEmployee("Marco", 433);
    addEmployee("Daniel", 500);     //Should not add it, since key already exists
    addEmployee("Alan", 125);

    printDict(myDictionary);

    return 0;
}

My research so far, and opens questions that I'm still trying to figure out:

Since std::unordered_map only add uniques keys, it will not add it anyways if I directly insert it, so no need for a check before it (?)
Going through the documentation for std::unordered_map, I only found find as member function, not find_if, so I'm assuming this is why it cannot be used. If not, then is find the best way to implement this program or using some other alternative like [] work better. (?)

Thanks a lot

You can directly check the bool returned by insert() to check whether there is already a key.

std::find_if is the wonrg tool for map. use return value of map::insert directly.

If you insist to use std::find_if, argument of predicate is const std::pair<const Key, Value>&.

[&newName](const auto &entry) { return newName == entry.first; } is the correct lambda, if you really want to use find_if. You also have to #include <algorithm> for it.

Since the name is the key in your unordered_map, you can simply use the unordered_map::find method to check whether it exists:
void addEmployee(std::string_view newName, int newTime)
{
    // first check if they name already exists, if it does then do nothing and return
    auto it = myDictionary.find(newName);
    if (it != myDictionary.end())
    {
        std::cout << "Name already exists! Wasn't added.\n";
        return;
    }
    // add employee into the map
    myDictionary.insert(std::pair<std::string_view, int>(newName, newTime));
}

Live demo
Some notes for completeness:

To answer your explicit question: find_if can also be used, but I see no advantage of using it over the straightforward find method (which is designed exactly for this purpose - search for an entry by  key). An example is shown in the answer by @Yksisarvinen (see that answer also for another alternative - using insert by itself).
std::string_view does not own the string it refers to. It's OK in your case (as posted) because you used string literals but if you need to create new strings it will be more robust to use std::strings as keys.


for completeness you could mention that std::find_if could be used, and why it shouldnt be. Thats the actual question

@463035818_is_not_an_ai done - added some notes for completeness.

std::unordered_map (and std::map for that matter) already makes sure that no duplicate keys can be stored. All you need to do is to check the return value of insert call:
void addEmployee(std::string_view newName, int newTime)
{
    auto [it, wasInserted] = myDictionary.insert(std::pair<std::string_view,int> (newName, newTime) );
    if(!wasInserted) {
        std::cout << "Name already exists! Wasn't added.\n";
    }
}

// or without C++17 structured bindings
void addEmployee(std::string_view newName, int newTime)
{
    auto insertResult = myDictionary.insert(std::pair<std::string_view,int> (newName, newTime) );
    if(!insertResult.second) {
        std::cout << "Name already exists! Wasn't added.\n";
    }
}

As Grace Hopper once said

It's easier to ask forgiveness than it is to get permission.

And it's true here. Checking if element exists in map after you try to insert it is much simpler than doing it before inserting.

If you need std::find_if for some other uses, it's also doable:
std::find_if(myDictionary.begin(), myDictionary.end(), [](const auto& pair){ /*do things*/ }
// or more verbosely
std::find_if(myDictionary.begin(), myDictionary.end(), [](const std::pair<const std::string_view, int>& pair){ /*do things*/ }


Final note: std::string_view doesn't own the string it points to. It's fine when you use string literals like in this example ("Daniel", "Marco", etc.), but the moment you try to manipulate them (e.g., create a string inside the program), std::string_view will fail.

The first code block would look a lot better if you used try_emplace instead of insert, or at least initialization with braces instead of std::pair explicitly.

void addEmployee( std::string_view newName, int newTime )
{
    // first check if they name already exists, if it does then do nothing and return
    auto insertRet = myDictionary.insert( { newName, newTime } );

    if( false == insertRet.second )
    {
        std::cout << "Name already exists! Wasn't added.\n";
    }
}


Welcome to StackOverflow. Please avoid posting code-only answers, try to explain what was changed and why. See [answer] for tips on how to write good answers.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
